# Is the chrome protocol local or online somewhere?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to know where the chrome:// directory, or website is. Is it a directory, or is there no documentation about it? I don't care if it's encrypted, or stored in a non-readable format, I honestly just want to know because I was thinking about that, and I had that question for a while. Just give me some kind of answer. Thank you!

Comment: In what OS? Windows> "C:\Users\Your user name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588549/1657610

Answer (score 0):

It's stored locally. Instead of making a separate settings window, chrome just display its settings in-browser.

Comment: He is asking for the file location where they are stored locally. How does the OP access the content whether encrypted or not. Are they in some internal database like SQL lite perhaps?